# HTML file not understanding Django content

Tags: html, django, intellij-idea, pycharm

I'm using Django in HTML file. Normally whatever IDE you use, understands the syntax the highlights `"load"` in `{% load xxxxx %}`. But in my case, Pycharm or Intelllij Idea is not understanding the syntax and the output file too give a result as text, `{% load xxxxx %}` included in the result page. The environment I am using I have already included Django in that. 
I'm not able to understand the issue. Can anyone please help me with this

Comment: You probably need an extension to syntacticall highlight elements.

Comment: By output file, do you mean the `html` page in the browser?

Comment: yes the html page

Comment: if you could add your output, we may be able to offer some help

Comment: the code - <!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>   output- {% load staticfiles %}

Comment: To view the output, you need to load the html content in your browser. You have currently pasted the html file here. Also, post the contents as part of the question. There's an edit option there.

Comment: can u explain it

Comment: How do you see the output of the code that you have written? You probably start your `django local server` and direct the `url` to the `path` that calls the corresponding `views` function that serves the respective `template` i.e your html file.

Comment: yes, the HTML web browser's page- my local host

Comment: What's the output when you go looking for the above template.

Comment: just this ---    {% load staticfiles %}

Comment: In the newer versions of `djnago`, you may use `{% load static %}`. Please visit the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/) for templates for more info.